# IOptionsMonitor monitors appsettings.json in the project root, not the one in assembly folder

Tags: asp.net, appsettings, ioptionsmonitor

I am developing a .Net 6.0 ASP.NET Core Web App in which `appsettings.json` is edited for admin purpose after the app has started. The information to be edited looks like:

```
{
  "Admin": {
    "WhiteList": ["::1",.....]
  },
  ....
```

which is modeled as

```
public class AdminOptions
{
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public string[] WhiteList { get; set; }
}
```

and configured in `Program.cs` as follows:

```
...
ver builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configuraion<AdminOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(AdminOptions.Admin));
```

`AdminOptions` is constructor-injected to a Singleton service which looks like:

```
public class WhiteChecker: IWhiteChecker
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<AdminOptions> optionsMonitor;

    public WhiteChecker(IOptionsMonitor<AdminOptions> monitor)
    {
        optionsMonitor = monitor;
    }
    
    .....[optionsMonitor.CurrentValue.WhiteList is consumed here].....
}
```

If `appsettings.json` in the **project root** is edited, `IOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue` returns the post-edit value of the pre-bound `WhiteList` property in `Admin` section, as expected.

However, if the one in **`AppContext.BaseDirectory`** (which I believe is the right place) is edited, `IOptionsMonitor` ignores.

I tried a change in `WebApplicationBuilder.Environment.ContentRootPath` (which is set to the project root by default) to `AppContext.BaseDirectory` before the `WebApplicationBuilder` is built at `Program.cs`, but the same result.

Is there any way to configure `IOptionsMonitor` to respond to the change in `appsettings.json` in `Appcontext.BaseDirectory`? Or do I misunderstand anything?

**UPDATE(10/11/2022)**

My way of setting `Environment.ContentRootPath` was wrong.

Wrong:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Environment.ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
```

Correct:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreteBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory
});
```

After setting correctly, `IOptionsMonitor` started to monitor the `appsettings.json` in `AppContext.BaseDirectory`.

The "Correct" version follows the way as instructed in [ASP.NET CORE6.0 doc>Migration>3.1/5.0 Code to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#change-the-content-root-app-name-and-environment).

I'm not sure why the "Wrong" version does not work, but it may be due to:

> The following variables are locked in early when initializing the host builders and can't be influenced by application config:
>
> - Application name
> - Environment name, for example Development,Production, and Staging
> - Content root
> - Web root ...

as described in [ASP.NET CORE6.0 doc>Fundamentals>Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#host-variables).

**UPDATE(10/13/2022)**

The behavior mentioned in the above quote is clearly reiterated at [ASP.NET CORE6.0 doc>Migrations>5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-the-aspnet-core-5-and-6-hosting-models):

> It's not possible to change any host settings such as app name, environment, or the content root after the creation of the WebApplicationBuilder.

The tricky part is that no exception is thrown if coded like the "Wrong" way above. It silently ignores the change by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue sounds like a non-issue according to the documentation provided by Microsoft.  I quote from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#content-root):

> During development, the content root defaults to the project's root directory. This directory is also the base path for both the app's content files and the Web root. Specify a different content root by setting its path when building the host. For more information, see Content root.

Same page, different [anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#content-root):

> The CreateDefaultBuilder method:
>
> - Sets the content root to the path returned by **GetCurrentDirectory**.

#### In Short...

What you see is the expected behavior:  The project's root for development, and when deployed somewhere, whatever is set for working directory.

Comment: I understood what I should configure is the directory my editor refers to instead of the one IOptionsMonitor refers to. Thanks!